# How to display any kind of url file in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

I can get any type of URL file like .pdf, .docx, .jpg, .txt and so on. I want to show them in Flutter. There are separate widgets for showing network images but I can't find any widget that can display any type of file.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this package for pdf files:

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pdfview

You can add jpg files by adding it to your assets folder and add it in an AssetImage Widget

```
const AssetImage(
 "assets/img/myFile.jpg",
),
```